# website down with mariadb "too many connections" error

Tags: mariadb

I am running a single high-visited website on a high-end Centos 7 VPS (16 vCore / 128 GB of RAM) running Plesk Onyx on 
Centos 7 / MariaDB 10.1 / PHP-FPM 5.6 setup.

Everything is usually smooth and fast, but it happened twice in a year that the website went down with the message "Too Many Connections" from MariaDB.

Being in a hurry to restore website I launched a " service mariadb restart "  without actually launching a SHOW PROCESSLIST.

I checked mariadb logs and web server logs afterwards and I haven't find anything useful to troubleshoot the issue.

Note that when it happened first time, I raised the max_connections value to 300 in my.cnf and constantly monitored the "max_used_connections" variabile seeing that value never went over 50 so I guessed it happened because of some DDOS attack or malicious attempt.

Questions :

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this ?

How can I be alerted if the max_used_connections value is approaching the max_connections value ? Any tool ?

I am using external pingdom service to check website uptime but it didn't detect this kind of problem (the web response is 200 OK) and also a netdata instance on the server (https://netdata.io/) that didn't help...

Comment: The two times this happened to me were due to a disk partition that was full, either with logs, or with deleted logs still held in memory.

Comment: Well, disk space is definitely not the culprit here :  # df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       394G   69G  310G  19% /

Comment: why do you want to restrict max_connections, anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Troubleshoot it by turning on the slowlog, preferably with a low value for `long_query_time` (such as "1").  Probably some naughty query will show up there.

Yes, do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` next time.  (Note "FULL".)  Instead of restarting mysqld, look for the offending query.  It will have one of the highest values in `Time` and it probably won't be in `Sleep` mode.  It may be something potentially long like `ALTER` or a dump.  Killing that one process will probably uncork the problem, and the problem will vanish in, perhaps, seconds.

Deleting a file that is "open" by a process (such as mysqld) will not help -- disk space is not recycled until all processes have closed the file.  Killing the process closes any open files.  Some logs are can be handled with `FLUSH LOGS;` -- this should be harmless, though it may not help.

If your tables are MyISAM, switching to InnoDB will avoid many cases of table locks (if that is what you are experiencing).

What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  For that sized RAM, about 80G is reasonable.

There might be some clues in the `GLOBAL STATUS`; see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning for analyzing it.  (Caution:  It will be useless immediately after a reboot.)

Comment: Yes - I am aware that launching a `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` during the issue would helped a lot, but I being in hurry I missed it - My bad :)  
Actually all tables of DB are InnoDB , my `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is 32G, altough the DB size is ~ 19GB


BTW - I am getting only those suggestions from mysqltuner (launched 2 days after lastest restart) :
join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
table_open_cache (> 401)
performance_schema = ON enable PFS


Actually I will keep monitored by I still haven't find a tool to be alerted on approaching "max_connection" value.

Comment: @user3256843 - Just watching `Threads_running` might suffice.  When over, say, 20, the system is in trouble -- it might settle down, or it might head for `max_connections`; in either case something naughty is going on and should be looked at.

Comment: @user3256843 - And..  Since you have so much RAM and that much data, you should probably increase the buffer_pool.